# How to show that these two determinants are equal?

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let $$f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3+a_4x^4\\
g(x) = b_0 + b_1x + b_2x^2 + b_3x^3+b_4x^4 \\ h(x) = c_0 + c_1x + c_2x^2 + c_3x^3+c_4x^4\\
\text{and }\; (x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma) = x^3+px^2+qx+r$$

Show that $$
\begin{vmatrix}
f(\alpha)&f(\beta)&f(\gamma)\\
g(\alpha)&g(\beta)&g(\gamma)\\
h(\alpha)&h(\beta)&h(\gamma)
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} 1&\alpha&\alpha^2\\1&\beta&\beta^2\\1&\gamma&\gamma^2
\end{vmatrix} .\begin{vmatrix}
a_0&a_1&a_2&a_3&a_4\\
b_0&b_1&b_2&b_3&b_4\\c_0&c_1&c_2&c_3&c_4\\r&p&q&1&0\\0&r&q&p&1\end{vmatrix}$$
This question in the book : "Problems in linear algebra" by I. V. Proskuryakov (1978). Their hint is express both side in to sum of some determinants, then showw that they are equals. Help me please! Thanks alot! (Sorry about my bad English, that also why i hesitate and can't provide more information for you guy).

Comment: Hint: if you develop the large determinant ($5\times5$) from the last row, you will get a sum of $4$ minors. Developing these from their last rows, you will eventually obtain a linear combination of $13$ $3\times3$ minors made of $a,b,c$ coefficients, with factors $p,q,r$ possibly squared. The products of the $3\times3$ determinants are also determinants of matrix products.

Comment: Should the $p$ and $q$ be interchanged in the fourth row of the $5\times 5$ matrix?